# Is it bad to install x11-common on debian server?

Tags: linux, debian, x11

We have a server based on Debian.
I must install imagemagick for editing images.
But when I type :

> apt-get install imagemagick

It tells me that the package **x11-common** will be installed
X11 is a package for GUI and I am on a server.

Is it dangerous ?

I don't want a gui...

Comment: It is also possible to install ImageMagick with a minimal set of dependencies: `sudo apt install --no-install-recommends imagemagick` That will prevent installing many X11-related packages.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I'm surprised it only loads x11-common, Imagemagick includes commands like display, that opened a window.

x11-common just contains a few config files/scripts as the package description says:

> x11-common contains the filesystem infrastructure required for further installation of the X Window System in any configuration; it does not provide a full installation of clients, servers, libraries, and utilities required to run the X Window System.

There are not even any client libraries, so you will not even be able to run the gui remotely.